# how to create a webhook in bitbucket jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

I'm trying to make a webhook between jenkins and bitbucket :
[image: jenkins trigger]

bitbucket webhook :
[image: webhook]

but when I click on the create btn I got this error :
[image: error]

any help please ?